# Long initialization in nodelet

Tags: ros-kinetic, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On page http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet#Threading_Model the following is written:

> 1.6.1 onInit

> This method is called on init and **should not block or do significant work**.

If the nodelet initialization process takes longer (e.g. reading data from database and process it etc.) what is the best practice to execute the long initialization process without blocking the `onInit()` call? One possible solution is to create a worker thread in the `onInit()` method which does the long initialization without blocking the call but I am wondering is there any "ROS pattern" to do this job?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283142/long-initialization-in-nodelet/) by [Tibor Takacs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33768/tibor-takacs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`onInit()` is called on the nodelet manager's callback thread, so it will block all other nodelets if you are using a single-threaded nodelet manager.

If you need to do a long-running initialization you could use a separate loader thread, or if you have C++11 you could use some of the async or futures primitives that were introduced in C++11.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1